# Android: How to change the Size of the RadioButton

Tags: android, size, radio-button

I have many `RadioButton`s in my app. The RadioButtons are too big for me. Is there any way to make them smaller?

Comment: I guess you could write your own control, but keep in mind that making the controls too small could make it harder for some users to hit the control accurately when in touch mode. This would reduce usability of your app.

Comment: I find this solution, see my answer here
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310577/6112256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310577/6112256)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't be done, the radio button is a built-in control component and as such its size is fixed.

Comment: It might not be easy to do it, but it is possible; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4787260/3063884

Comment: Please don't reply esp. with negative remarks as "it can't be done" etc., without being certain!

See, Michael has an easy and workable solution!

Comment: There is a alternative approach.by creating custom radio button. See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68220214/5039264

Answer (score 65):

One quick hacky solution is to scale the button down:

```
<RadioButton
  android:scaleX="0.5"
  android:scaleY="0.5" />
```

This works great for going smaller.

For going larger, this tends to cause some clipping from the container View, so you'll likely have to hardcode the height/width of the RadioGroup to fit the scaled buttons.  The button drawable can also get noticeably pixelated the larger you go, so it's not really great if you want something 3x larger...

Comment: and adding  android:textSize="[size]sp" will scale the radio button label too , but matching the button and label size needs some more hard code ...

Comment: Shrinks the button size but leaves bigger spaces between them

Answer (score 15):

you can use scalex and scaley properties , then use translationX and translationY to put it in the radiobutton windows.

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtnfkilo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleX="1.4"
            android:scaleY="1.4"
            android:text="Kilogram"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:translationX="24dp" />
```

Answer (score 13):

It *can* be done but is not as simple as setting the Layout_Width and Layout_height as with EditTexts, Buttons etc. To modify the size/looks of a view like a checkbox/radio button use the "Background" and "Button" properties to specify your own drawables.

This is an older page, and the locations are different now, but this'll give you an idea :
http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html

Comment: This is a broken link.

Answer (score 3):

I relpaced `RadioButton` with `ToggleButton` and applied same style. I did override background and button.

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/btnToggle1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        style="@style/ToggleButtonStyle"
        android:button="@null"
        android:textOn="@string/btnTitle"
        android:textOff="@string/btnTitle"/>
```

and style:

```
<style name="ToggleButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_radiobutton</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_text_radiobutton</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@null</item>
</style>
```

Works for me - looks the same, but with custom height.

If your RadioButton is in the RadioGroup, you will need to customize listener, check
[Android: How to get a radiogroup with togglebuttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Android Vector Asset Studio have icons for unchecked, checked radio button.
You can import this vector then change the color by change `android:tint` inside the vector xml

[image]

Then set the `background` for `RadioButton` like

**bg_radio_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_radio_button_unchecked_24" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_radio_button_checked_24" />
</selector>
```

**..xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_24"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_24"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_radio_selector"
        android:button="@null" />
```

Now you are able to change the size of `RadioButton` to any size you want but maybe it hard to click because the click area is quite small.
To increase the click area, we can use this function (note that padding will not work because we use the `background` property for `RadioButton`) (solution from [How to increase hit area of Android button without scaling background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176105/how-to-increase-hit-area-of-android-button-without-scaling-background/35721966))

```
fun View.increaseTouchArea(pixel: Int) {
    val parent = parent as View
    parent.post {
        val rect = Rect()
        getHitRect(rect)
        rect.top -= pixel
        rect.left -= pixel
        rect.bottom += pixel
        rect.right += pixel
        parent.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(rect, this)
    }
}
```

**and**

```
yourRadioButton.increaseTouchArea(context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_12))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative approach to change the size.
Import radio button checked and unchecked from vector asset.

### Create three drawable

**radio_button_check**

- specify any width and height

**radio_button_uncheck**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:width="60dp"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked" />
    </layer-list>
```

**custom_radio_button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_check" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_uncheck"></item>
</selector>
```

### Radio button

**In radio Button**

```
<RadioButton                                       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                       
    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="39dp"
    android:text="1" />
```

In case to change the text size use "android:textSize" property

In image first one is the custom radio button and second one is  default one

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found one workaround for this

we need to use this text/symbol `⭘` and `◉` instead of radio button and add radio button functionality to them.

EXAMPLE:

first create Linear layout for button text and title text

XML

```
         <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn1Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="⭘"
                    android:textSize="34sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn1txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Option 1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn2Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="⭘"
                    android:textSize="34sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn2txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Option 2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```

```
        LinearLayout btn1Layout = findViewById(R.id.btn1Layout);
        LinearLayout btn2Layout = findViewById(R.id.btn2Layout);
```

```
        TextView btn1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        TextView btn2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn1.setText(⭘);
        btn2.setText(⭘);
        
      if(selectedId != null) {
      
        TextView selectedBtn = (TextView) findViewById(selectedId);
        selectedBtn.setText(◉); 
      }
```

then set click listners to the all Layouts for updating btn symbols.

```
   btn1Layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedId = btn1.getId();
                btn1.setText(◉);
                btn2.setText(⭘);
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"               
            android:layout_height="50dp"           
            android:orientation="horizontal"         
            android:checkedButton="@+id/first">  

 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/first"        
      android:width="50dp"        
      android:height="50dp"        
      android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/> 

   <RadioButton android:id="@+id/second"        
      android:width="50dp"     
      android:height="50dp"     
      android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>

   <RadioButton android:id="@+id/third"
      android:width="50dp"
      android:height="50dp"
      android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>

   <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fourth"                                          
      android:width="50dp"              
      android:height="50dp"           
      android:button="@drawable/button_radio"/>           
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: ths doesn't scale the internal radio button style