# How to decrease the size of image displayed on radio button in android without using new image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.1-eclair

I have designed an activity in which i have two radio button
but those size are more than enough i want to decrease it 
i am using text size that decreases only text 
if layout size is decrease that decrease only view not radio button circle

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RG1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/N"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="12dip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="No"
            android:textSize="12dip" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: You can give `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for each `RadioButton`. But your question title and the question are a bit different. In your title, you ask about how to decrease the size of **image** displayed, but in your question and code, you don't seem to use any image. Please re-frame your question.

Comment: yes i want to decrease size of default image not new image

Comment: _My question_: Where's the image, mate?

Comment: No.. It;s not possible to change the size of default radio button's image.... If you want you can set your own image to radio button and adjust its size.. that will be the better solution to achieve your goal rather than wasting time to change radio button's image....

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use a Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/1" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/2" 
    android:state_checked="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/3" 
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/4" />  
</selector>
```

and in the radiobutton tag you can add

```
android:button="@drawable/above"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Hope it helpe. You might also want to have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may be useful for you : [Android: How to change the Size of the RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014597/android-how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radiobutton)

You probably force to use another picture as their background

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me!

```
button.getCompoundDrawables();
compoundDrawables[1].setBounds(10, 10, 90, 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use your custom drawables for radio button's state. To decrease the image size for custom drawables check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437223/how-to-decrease-radio-button-drawable-size/35550901#35550901) out.

Comment: Exactly duplicate of @Alish Answere

Comment: No sir, its different. When you use a custom drawable its a great pain to reduce its size on the radio button. Yes, it doesn't satisfy your need of not using  a new image ,but, for any one who has faced difficulty reducing the size of the custom drawable ,just as I did , it works wonderfully well.

Comment: And by the way for FYI, @Alish's answer tells you to **reduce the size of the radio button** but what I am talking about is to **reduce the size of image on radio button**

Answer (score 0):

visit this page http://android-holo-colors.com/ , select Radio and download the output resources (zip file contains a "res" folder), That contains all images for all posible radio button states, replace images with your custom but keeping the size of the download files. If you think it has too much states simply erase from selector in xml drawable theme.

[image]