# how to allow only 1 android toggle button out of 3 to be on at once

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

i am using 3 toggle buttons. In my android application i would like that only 1 of these toggle buttons can be selected at once. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: You can use a RadioGroup  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html). See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [radio buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html).  If you don't want that, check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#ToggleButton) - it shows you how to listen for changes to the button state.  If you find that one of your buttons is changed, change the other 2 to the off state.

Answer (score 14):

A simple onChangeListener will do:

```
public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {

ToggleButton one; 
ToggleButton two;
ToggleButton three;
ToggleButton four;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    one = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    two = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    three = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    four = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton4);

    one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
    two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
    three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
    four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
}

OnCheckedChangeListener changeChecker = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            if (buttonView == one) {
                two.setChecked(false);
                three.setChecked(false);
                four.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (buttonView == two) {
                one.setChecked(false);
                three.setChecked(false);
                four.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (buttonView == three) {
                two.setChecked(false);
                one.setChecked(false);
                four.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (buttonView == four) {
                two.setChecked(false);
                three.setChecked(false);
                one.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Why CompoundButton vs. RadioGroup?

Answer (score 9):

ThePikeman's solution is okay, but depending on how many buttons you have you might want to consider an array that you can iterate over.

For a small number of buttons, Pikeman's code can be simplified to save some typing...

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
      if (buttonView != one) {
        one.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView != two) {
        two.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView != three) {
        three.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView != four) {
        four.setChecked(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function;

```
private void setIsChecked(CheckBox checkBox){
      buttonOne.setChecked(false);
      buttonTwo.setChecked(false);
      buttonThree.setChecked(false);
      checkBox.setChecked(true)
}
```

now all of them are deemed except for the one you choose

ex

```
setIsChecked(buttonOne);
```

Now only button one is checked and etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MaterialButtonToggleGroup
you just need to use this property in your xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
   ...
   app:singleSelection="true"
   ...>
```