# Why cant I access the children of the radio group

Tags: android, radio-button

I am trying to use this [Android: How to get a radiogroup with togglebuttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons)  code of the given answer

but in

```
static final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup radioGroup, final int i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < radioGroup.getChildCount(); j++) {
                final ToggleButton view = (ToggleButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(j);
                view.setChecked(view.getId() == i);
            }
        }
    };
```

in  line

> final ToggleButton view = (ToggleButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(j);

it always crashes. In Logcat I don't see any message.

I tried everything I could think of , but can't fid the problem - 
Many thanks!

ps this is my xml for the radiogroup:

```
   <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup2" android:layout_width="150sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingLeft = "10sp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/a2"  >
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Settings_otherSettingsT2Yes" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/Settings_otherSettingsT2Yes" android:checked="false"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Settings_otherSettingsT2No" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/Settings_otherSettingsT2No"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
```

...nothing special here

I checked the number of children by logging `radioGroup.getChildCount()` and it gives 2 as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you cast RadioButtons to ToggleButton. This is likely to be the cause of your crashes. I don't understand why you can't find an exception in logcat.

However, you say you want to use code like in the link, but your XML is not close to the link. You use RadioButtons where the link uses ToggleButtons.

If you just want RadioButtons, then completely disregard that link.
If you want to use ToggleButtons then that link isn't the best way anyway. Adding ToggleButtons to a RadioGroup just confuses the intent of the code.

Comment: by the way, could you please explain what's the use/difference of setOnCheckedChangeListener and setOnClickListener for those radio buttons. Only setOnCheckedChangeListener is triggered when I touch the screen. setOnClickListener never fires - allthough there are so many samples that use this.. thanks!