# Android three button states (pressed, not pressed and default)

Tags: android, button, background, state

When the layout loads, all buttons would have default state/bg (without state in selector). When the button is pressed, the background for that button would change to button_pressed="true" and for all the others too button_pressed="false". Is it possible?

With this code a default background is button_pressed="false" item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- pressed -->
<item
  android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClicked" />
<item 
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/buttonNotClicked" />
<item 
android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to get a radiogroup with togglebuttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button_selector` should look like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Here you can have 3 states i.e `button_normal`(when button is in normal condition), `button_focused`(when button is focused to be pressed) and `button_pressed`(after the button has been pressed)..

So use 4 different drawables(in `/res/drawable` folder) with names below :

1. `button_selector.xml`(For selector)
2. `button_normal.xml`(normal button)
3. `button_focused.xml`(button when focused)
4. `button_pressed.xml`(button when pressed)

Hope it helps!
Let me know if I can help you for anything else...

Comment: I'm glad it works for you :)
Let me know if you want help for  anything else :)

Comment: How can I do this programmatically in java class