# multiple toggle button enable or disable in a single method

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I have a 3 toggleButtons and if 1 is enabled other 2 will be disabled. I am able to achieve this through if statement. But I need to write different if for all the toggleButtons.

```
 case toggleButton1:
            if(toggleButton[0].isChecked())
            {
                toggleButton[1].setEnabled(false);
                toggleButton[2].setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleButton[1].setEnabled(true);
                toggleButton[2].setEnabled(true);
            }
        break;

 case R.id.toggleButton2:

            if(toggleButton[1].isChecked())
            {
                toggleButton[0].setEnabled(false);
                toggleButton[2].setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleButton[0].setEnabled(true);
                toggleButton[2].setEnabled(true);
            }

            break;

case R.id.toggleButton3:
            if(toggleButton[2].isChecked())
            {
                toggleButton[1].setEnabled(false);
                toggleButton[0].setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleButton[1].setEnabled(true);
                toggleButton[0].setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
```

How can I group this in to a single method?

EDIT:

How about if i try like below.

```
          private void toggle(int i) {
           if(i==0) {j=1,k=2} elseif(i==1) {j=0,k=2}else{j=0,k=1}

            if(toggleButton[i].isChecked())
            {
                toggleButton[j].setEnabled(false);
                toggleButton[k].setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleButton[j].setEnabled(true);
                toggleButton[k].setEnabled(true);
            }

           }
```

Comment: this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837927/7073808

Comment: @UltimateDevil - i want to enable and disable the button so i didnt go for radio group.

Comment: i think you have to use if else statements if you simplify above method than also

Answer (score 0):

try this use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of toggleButton

```
toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
    {
        toggleButton[1].setEnabled(false);
        toggleButton[2].setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        toggleButton[1].setEnabled(true);
        toggleButton[2].setEnabled(true);
    }

}
});
```

Comment: i want to simplify to single method so that i dont need to use the so many if's.

Comment: @user2269164 you should use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` when perticular toggleButton is checked or unchecked than add your logic in it

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this

```
private static class OnToggleButtonChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    private final ToggleButton toggleButton1;
    private final ToggleButton toggleButton2;

    public OnToggleButtonChangeListener(ToggleButton toggleButton1, ToggleButton toggleButton2){
        this.toggleButton1 = toggleButton1;
        this.toggleButton2 = toggleButton2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        toggleButton1.setEnabled(!isChecked);
        toggleButton2.setEnabled(!isChecked);
    }
}
```

Assign it the listener to the button and supply the 2 buttons that shall be disabled if the toggle-state changes

```
toggleButtonXy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnToggleButtonChangeListener(toggleButtonX, toggleButtonY));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code :

```
private void setChecked(int id) {
    try {
        ToggleButton[] toogles = {toogle1, toogle2, toogle3};



        for (int i = 0; i < toogles.length; i++) {
            if (id != i) {
                toogles[i].setEnabled(false);

            } else {
                toogles[i].setEnabled(true);

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch(buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                btn2.setEnabled(!isChecked);
                btn3.setEnabled(!isChecked);
            break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                btn1.setEnabled(!isChecked);
                btn3.setEnabled(!isChecked);
            break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                btn1.setEnabled(!isChecked);
                btn2.setEnabled(!isChecked);
            break;
    }
}
```