# Toggle button with radio button behaviour

Tags: android, radio-button, togglebutton, radio-group, android-togglebutton

I have a set of toggle buttons in a relative layout.

A user should be able to select only one toggle button at a time.

I have tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons) but none of them seem to work.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: what you have done show code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It's not working probably because of all RadioButtons are not grouped together because of some View between them.

RadioButton should be the direct child of RadioGroup, Otherwise grouping does not work.

Answer (score -1):

> A user should be able to select only one toggle button at a time.

The code available in selected [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837927/10372900) at your given link is doing the same job. To visualize this, change some code.

**In XML**

In ToggleButton, change `android:textOn` and `android:textOff` to 'on' and 'off' (Just for example). Your XML file should look like this:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textOn="on"
        android:textOff="off"
        android:onClick="onToggle"
        android:checked="true"
        />
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textOn="on"
        android:textOff="off"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onToggle"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

This should look like this:

[image: Screenshot1]

**In Java file**

In your activity, write this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleListener);
}

static final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup radioGroup, final int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < radioGroup.getChildCount(); j++) {
            final ToggleButton view = (ToggleButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(j);
            view.setChecked(view.getId() == i);
        }
    }
};

public void onToggle(View view) {
    ((RadioGroup)view.getParent()).check(view.getId());
    // write your specific code here ..
    Toast.makeText(this, "Toggle button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When you click 'off' while another (toggle button) is 'on', 'off' will change to 'on' and vice versa. So user is able to select only one toggle button at a time. If one toggle button is on, other will always be off.

Comment: it was my fault. Delete it.

Comment: Was the answer helpful? Please reconsider your vote.