# How to make a button remain selected even after release?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button, android-togglebutton

I'm trying to make a button stay clicked after a user chooses it. My program is a 10 question quiz where if a user chooses an option and then return to that question, it should be displayed as chosen.

I can't seem to figure out a way to display the button as clicked when switching between questions.

```
mAButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "A Button Clicked");
            answers[questionIndex] = "Question: " + questionIndex + ", Answer: A";
            Toast t;
            t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.recorded_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
});
```

This is an example of the onClick I have for one of the answers(I have 5 buttons for the answers). I want it so that if a user chose this answer, the button will stay clicked until they chose a different answer. I've tried some things I've seen online but nothing is working well so far.

Edit: Each question is multiple choice with 5 answers!

Comment: Is it a multiple choice question?

Comment: @M.Zain yes it is, I forgot to mention that!

Comment: please check the answer, wish it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a single answer is allowed to be checked among the list of answers, you need to use [RadioButtons](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton)

If multiple answers are allowed to be checked, you need to use [CheckBoxes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox) or [ToggleButtons](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton)

Here is a snippet of using ToggleButtons which simulates the button as clicked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:textOff="Unselected"
        android:textOn="Selected" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:textOff="Unselected"
        android:textOn="Selected" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:textOff="Unselected"
        android:textOn="Selected" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        android:textOff="Unselected"
        android:textOn="Selected" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and create a drawable for the background selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/checked_button" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/unchecked_button" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

colors

```
<resources>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    ...
    <color name="checked_button">#989898</color>
    <color name="unchecked_button">#f8f8f8</color>

</resources>
```

Java:

```
ToggleButton button1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
ToggleButton button2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
ToggleButton button3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
ToggleButton button4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);

button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Button1 is checked
        } else {
            // Button1 is unchecked
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using [RadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton)s inside of a [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup).

See [the guide in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) for more.

If that doesn't help you solve your issue, please [clarify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use a RadioGroup. And fill it with ToggleButton (looks closest to the regular buttons). [Another answer which shows how to set this up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379527/android-how-to-get-a-radiogroup-with-togglebuttons) Then you can retrieve the Id of the ToggleButton that was left clicked using "radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();" [How to get checked option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton)