# How to make BottomNavigationView in Android scroll when there are more icons than will fit without shrinking them?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a navigation bar with three tabs.

[image: Nav bar - 3 tabs]

I'd like to add a fourth and have them scroll. Instead when I add a fourth, the icons shrink and the names disappear until one of he tabs is selected.

[image: Nav bar - 4 tabs]

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you add your xml? FYI bottom navigation is not scrollable and should not contain more than 5 icons.

Comment: scrolling items in BottomNavigationView is discouraged by material design

Comment: I know it's discouraged. The guidelines also say "3-5" so i was hoping I'd be able to actually use 5 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setLabelVisibilityMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.html#setLabelVisibilityMode(int)) gives the option for label to be displayed permanently against the items.

BottomNavigationView doesn't allow scrolling functionality as it is against the [design guidelines](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#placement).

> **Don’t.**
>
> Bottom navigation bar destinations don’t scroll.

If you were insistent, you could create a similar design using a RadioGroup and a series of ToggleButtons similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837927/12652302) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for showing both text and icons on BottomNevigationView for 3 to 5 items and stop shifting.

```
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

**1. Add this some line of code in BottomNevigationView as shown**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/seventy_dp"
     android:layout_semitransparent="true"
     android:background="@color/colorBottomNev"
     android:showAsAction="always|withText"
     app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
     app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
     app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
     app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
     app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

**2. Add Menu Items like as follows:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_catalogue"
        android:icon="@drawable/catalogue"
        android:title="@string/catalogue"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contracts"
        android:icon="@drawable/contract"
        android:title="@string/contracts"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_prospects"
        android:icon="@drawable/prospect"
        android:title="@string/prospects"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_performance"
        android:icon="@drawable/performance"
        android:title="@string/performance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_advance"
        android:icon="@drawable/advance"
        android:title="@string/advance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

**3. Add this style in style.xml file:**

```
     <style name="BottomNavigationViewTextStyle">
                <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montmedium</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
                <item name="android:duplicateParentState">true</item>
                <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
                <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
       </style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```